# get method using of passing data to a URL

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, get

I have a simple form where I want to use to pass a url pram to *example.com*.
my current code just passes the data to mu current URL and dose not get the URL I have set in JavaScript.

the outcome im hoping for is example.com/?name=test&email=test%40gmail.com, I need to data and URL to be handled via JS.

Can someone tell me where I have gone wrong?

```js
function setAction(event) {
e.preventDefault()
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var formURL = "https://example.com";
    $.ajax(
        {
            url : formURL,
            type: "get",
            data : postData,
            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                alert("pass")
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert("fail")
            }
        })
   
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form onsubmit="return setAction(event)">
    <div>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input id="email" name="email" type="email">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="submit" type="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: instead of postData after serialize just append it to URL

Comment: Note that `example.com` will have to be explicitly configured to allow your code to access it.

Comment: _“Can someone tell me where I have gone wrong?”_ - the browser console can. `e` does not exist, at the point where you try `e.preventDefault();`. And due to that error, the normal form submit is _not_ suppressed, and that leads to the parameters getting added to _your_ current URL, when the form submission happens.

Comment: @Pointy so on the site example.com I need to accept the get ?

Comment: Code from your domain will only be allowed access to another domain via an xhr if the other domain responds with headers (CORS) that tells the browser it's OK. If the other site does not do that, and you cannot change the other site, you can't do it from the browser at all. It's basic Internet security. You can create a proxy for the other site on your own server, however.

Comment: @Pointy the actual URL ill be posting to is a subdomain and can pass data to, is my problem because im running the code local ?

Comment: Yes, if you *control* the other domain, it's not a problem and you can make it work. The browser doesn't know who owns what domain; it just compares the domain names literally, and they're either the same or they're not.

Comment: Your problem is first of all the error I pointed out earlier - have you fixed that by now? _“is my problem because im running the code local ?”_ - depends on your definition of “local”. If you are just accessing your document via the file system, and not at least via a local web server (so that everything happens over HTTP), then don’t expect cross-origin requests to work, that gets usually blocked by browsers.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, just moved the e.preventDefult to the top